# similar words replace with a new word

Tags: python, string, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group_code": ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '222', '222','222', '222', '222', '222'],
    "ind_code": ['Credit pay', 'PAYMENT', 'loan payment', 'bill payment', 'pays', 'PayMent', 'Payer', 'Rev12','Rev11','13 rev','Rev13','Rev .!','REV 17']
})
```

Now i need to group all the similar words in the "ind_code" and my DF should look like this :

All "ind_code" with word as "pay" in it (irrespective of case, in front or last or in middle) it should be replaced with "Payment"
Similarly, all word with "rev" should be replaced with Rev

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just replace the words, which are having similar pattern you can use this snippet

```
df.loc[df.ind_code.str.contains(r'[Pp][Aa][Yy]'),'ind_code']='Payment'
df.loc[df.ind_code.str.contains(r'[Rr][Ee][Vv]'),'ind_code']='Rev'
```

Edit

```
df.ind_code.str.extract(r'([PpRr][AaEe][YyVv])').str.lower().map({'pay':'Payment','rev':'Rev'})
```

Out:

```
    group_code  ind_code
0   111 Payment
1   111 Payment
2   111 Payment
3   111 Payment
4   111 Payment
5   111 Payment
6   111 Payment
7   222 Rev
8   222 Rev
9   222 Rev
10  222 Rev
11  222 Rev
12  222 Rev
```

Comment: @Thanks Naga, Let me try it

Comment: hi @Sheriff , please accept the answer if it works for your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_(row):
    if 'pay' in row.lower():
        return 'Payment'
    if 'rev' in row.lower():
        return 'Rev'
    return row
df.ind_code = df.ind_code.apply(lambda row : replace_(row))
print(df)
output:

   group_code ind_code
0         111  Payment
1         111  Payment
2         111  Payment
3         111  Payment
4         111  Payment
5         111  Payment
6         111  Payment
7         222      Rev
8         222      Rev
9         222      Rev
10        222      Rev
11        222      Rev
12        222      Rev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just an additional query.

Comment: if want to check if 'pay' or 'mkt' in row.lower(): retrun 'Payment'

Comment: Will it work ? basically i wanted to check if 2 to 3 letters or substring is there ? if so then replace it with the given string

Comment: yes. define all the relevant strings in a list and use any(). a=['pay','mkt']. if any([i in row.lower() for i in a]):

Comment: Is it possible to fetch those records which as only numeric in it ? in the same logic ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"group_code": ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '111', 
                                  '111','222','222','222','222','222','222'], 
                     "ind_code": ['Credit pay', 'PAYMENT', 'loan payment', 'bill payment', 
                                  'pays', 'PayMent', 'Payer','Rev12',
                                  'Rev11','13 rev','Rev13','Rev .!','REV 17']})

conditions = [df['ind_code'].str.contains('(pay)', case=False) , df['ind_code'].str.contains('(rev)', case=False)]
choices = ['pay', 'rev']
df['result'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='unclear')
df
```

https://regexr.com/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it and get back.